# What is Justice? - Has Several Downvotes. Advice on how to rephrase

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Justice is fundamental to actions of law operators.  As my question states, it is even a mandate (as criminal code) in many jurisdictions that justice take precedence over prosecution.

I suspect the downvotes are ad hominem since the question obviously exposes lawyers especially judges as charlatans; however, surely, there is a solid answer to expose *me* as being grossly uninformed and confused.  Anyone?...

Comment: Point of information: saying that a post on the Internet "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" is not an *ad hominem* attack, whatever the motive may be.  Suggesting that seven people about whom you know literally nothing are motivated by financial dishonesty is.

Answer (score 6):

Your question, as stated, isn't a neutral request for information – it should be. By insisting on statutes defining "justice", you've especially made it impossible to answer the question, since justice is never statutorily defined. There is a domain of law, jurisprudence, which addresses such questions; and there is, outside of the domain of law (and in the domain of philosophy), a wide range of theories of what constitutes justice. There is some intersection of these two currents.

There are probably legal studies (i.e. articles in law reviews) which address the concept "justice" from a more legal perspective, in particular looking at case law and characterizing what facts lead justices to find a decision to be "just" versus "unjust". A request for the leading legal literature on that topic would be reasonable, and if framed as an objective question about the nature of law, might not get so heavily downvoted and closed.

Comment: Wrong.  Read the statute I cited as a single example.  SHALL ... JUSTICE is done.  Am I missing something?  Please, do educate me.  (BTW my account has been closed here by the "honorable" moderators.)

Comment: Also, much of my responses to the nonsensical noise here is deleted by your "honorable" moderators.  Literally, I write, and POOF.  It disappears...

Answer (score 2):

Even your question points out, "What is Justice?" has been debated *as a matter of  philosophy* for thousands of years.  The question is often raised and addressed in judicial opinions, with answers as varied as the person answering and the specific circumstances in question.  What you ask is a matter of opinion and ongoing debate, and hence is not amenable to a good answer on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56591/discussion-on-answer-by-feetwet-what-is-justice-has-several-downvotes-advice).